# Share the remotes that are added locally to make working with git subtree a bit easier

Tags: git, git-subtree

Going through the tutorial here: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-subtree

On the surface it seems that `subtrees` are more work than `submodules` with multiple members on the team.

For example, if I have 10 submodules and add an 11th one the submodule remote url is added to the repository itself. All my colleagues have to do is run `git submodule update --init --recursive` and things work as expected. They don't need to know the submodule details.

With subtree, I have to either add a script or ask all my colleagues to manually add the remotes. From the tutorial: `git remote add -f tpope-vim-surround https://bitbucket.org/vim-plugins-mirror/vim-surround.git`. This is tedious and error prone (or requires us to maintain a script to add the remotes - which *could* lead to conflicts if there is a remote name that already exists).

This becomes even more painful when a new maintainer joins the group and now has to setup all 11 remotes. I hope I am missing something here that makes subtrees easier to use in a large team?

Comment: For us, the reason we are trying to switch to subtees is 1) so that we can have worktrees (submodules do not work well with worktrees) and 2) there are plugins for the engine we are using that do not play well with submodules